# Removing CRLF in Access Query so doesn't screw up the export

Tags: ms-access

I'm going crazy here is my access SQL but I keep getting the awesome compiler error that won't tell me anything....ughh

```
UPDATE Inspector_OutputSynchronization 
SET [Inspector_OutputSynchronization].[Updates] = 
    Replace([Inspector_OutputSynchronization].[Updates], CHR(13), "-");
```

I need to replace the Carecter returns so it doesn't impact text exports

Comment: what is the awesome compiler error?

Comment: Compile error. in query expression 'Replace([Inspector_OutputSynchronization].[Updates], CHR(13), "-".

Comment: A stab in the dark here, but is that statement in a VBA module or in a query? If in a VBA module, you need to use `""-"");`, assuming your query is being assigned to a string variable. If not, we need more info on your problem. It's working for me if I paste it into a query.

Comment: I'm trying to leverage a SQL query not VBA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CRLF is 2 characters ... `Chr(13) & Chr(10)`.

```
UPDATE Inspector_OutputSynchronization 
SET [Updates] = Replace([Updates], Chr(13) & Chr(10), "-");
```

Comment: Dang I wished that worked, I'll provide whatever info needed to solve this, but it's a query I'm trying to write.  I get the following with that code in the SQL View in Access Compile error. in query expression 'Replace[Updates], Chr(13) & Chr(10), "-"'.

Should this be ran in VB??

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have any missing references in your VBA modules.

Tools->Macro->Visual Basic Editor.

In the VB Editor, go to Tools->References and make sure nothing says "MISSING:". If there is something, try un-checking it and going to Debug->Compile Access9db (or whatever the project name is).

If you get a compilation error, you are missing a reference to something (probably another version of the thing you just un-checked).

If you don't get a compilation error, re-try your query.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I am trying to do this via SQL Query

Comment: If you are in MS-Access, check your references anyway. This is a MAJOR source of confusion, because Replace() and Chr() are VBA functions, not SQL (even though you can use them in your queries). When your references are messed up you can get weird errors where you wouldn't think you would.